# How to draw ray diagrams for a compound microscope

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, microscopy

I am trying to draw the ray diagram of a compound microscope. Here is my attempt (sorry if the image is kind of blurry):

[image]

I believe that I understand how the objective lens creates a real image (I decided to draw my diagram so that this real image would form on top of $f_{ep}$). A line that hits perpendicular to the lens is forced to bend through the location $f_{ob}$, and a line that passes through the center of the lens is not bent at all. By finding where these two lines intersect, I can determine the location and size of the real image.

The part where I get confused is how to determine what an observer looking through the eyepiece lens actually sees. Is there a way to do it precisely, like I did for the location and size of the real image? I get very confused in optics when you introduce an observer how to determine what they actually see.

Comment: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/26-4-microscopes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an object at the location of the intermediate image between the lenses and consider two rays in particular directions from that object (even though they may not actually be there - it's just to find the location of the image). Again you can choose one ray going through the center of the eyepiece, which will go straight through. Choose the other ray parallel to the axis, which will meet the axis a distance $f_{ep}$ to the right of the eyepiece. These should be parallel and give the direction of the image the observer sees.  Like here:
[Diagram of compound microscope.](https://mycbseguide.com/questions/466760/)
The actual two rays that you've drawn will not strike the eyepiece at these convenient directions, but they must refract to be parallel nonetheless.